# Placement new to initialize inplace object

Tags: c++, initialization, new-operator, placement-new

I recently came across a rather interesting serialization approach that utilized the transparency (common undefined behavior among compilers?) of uninitialized variables for "efficient" deserialization.

Memory is allocated and assigned a predetermined value. Placement new is then used to instantiate a struct (for example a complex inplace data structure) "initializing" the uninitialized variables to the value of the underlying memory. (see code below)

Besides from being rather risky and possibly not a very agreeable coding convention... I was just wondering whether anyone had come across this method or more importantly -- what is it called?

```
class SomeClass {
public:
  SomeClass() {}

  int someInt;
};

int main(...) {
  int dummy = 42;

  int *pSomeClass = new (&dummy) SomeClass();
  cout << pSomeClass->someInt << endl;
}
```

This will print out the number 42... neato!

Answer (score 5):

It's called "relying on UB" or, in laymen's terms, "foolishness".

Comment: @David: `pSomeClass::someInt` is not initialised.

Comment: The layout of a `struct` and a `class` is well-defined though, or is it not?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Padding, alignment... and I don't see what that has to do with it.

Comment: The first member is always at offset 0, as I understand things. I must admit I don't see why it wouldn't always be easier to initialize in the constructor.

Comment: @David: Regardless, in the context of the new object, that member has not been initialised. Placement new may imbue some more lenient policies here, but if it does then I'm not aware of them [yet].

Comment: Is that because it's C++ rather than C?

Comment: @David: You'll have to be more specific. They are separate languages with separate rules.

Comment: The problem is that the ctor is called, and _may_ initialize `someInt`. A reasonable compiler, in ISO-conforming debug mode, may set `someInt` to `0xDEADBEEF`. You can't assume it will be initialized, but you can't assume that it will be not-initialised either.

Comment: @MSalters: In the OP's example it's explicit that the member is not initialised; he's asking what it's called when we rely on using the uninitialised value.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen this done in eCos, an RTOS, to initialize some of their kernel objects.

As pointed out by Tomalak one of the draw-backs is no virtual functions allowed.
They try to ensure that by testing for equal size `sizeof(kernel object) == sizeof(variable used for initialization)`.

Their code although was way more complex using a C-struct to mimic the C++ class member variables for the c interface instead of using C functions to get/set the variables in the C++ class

Although the behaviour they went for there was the exact opposite, they used values from the C++ class, set in the constructor, to fill the memory from `placement new`.

I do not advise on doing this tho.